# How to select Month Between in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
ID     Name         **Month(Varchar column)**
23     Raj          January
435    Amit Kumar   February
54     Mohan        March
546    Mohan        March
56     Raj          January
57     Ani          December
58     Moni         April
59     Soni         September
```

how to write a query to select data between **January and April**

Comment: I'm sure you are already aware of this, but just in case you aren't: your database design is poor. You should use a date or an integer field to store the month.

Comment: +1 Good question with a good answer

Comment: He posts the answer that worked for him in his blog, as if it was his idea...

Answer (score 3):

You would make your job much more easy if you would store actual dates or month numbers.

If you have to live with the current table structure, you need to translate the month names into their corresponding number. Theses numbers can be compared:

```
select ID, Name, Month from (
    select ID, Name, Month, 
        case Month 
            when 'January' then 1
            when 'February' then 2
            ...
        end as MonthNo
    from 
        Table
 ) as TranslatedTable
 where
    MonthNo between 1 and 4
```

Comment: If you need this in multiple queries, you may want to create a lookup table to hold the MonthName and MonthValue fields.

Answer (score 1):

As your data is not comparable, you would need to supply all possible values in the range:

```
select ID, Name
from TheTable
where Month in ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April')
```

Comment: i know this but i have to give month according to condition so it is not possible to use this query